# Hibernate Search and Hibernate Core Compatibility Issue in Sring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm using spring boot v`3.1.2` with **spring-boot-starter-data-jpa**

After adding the Hibernate Search dependency I got the following error

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.hibernate.search.cfg.impl.SearchConfigurationFromHibernateCore.<init>(SearchConfigurationFromHibernateCore.java:80)

The following method did not exist:

    'org.hibernate.MultiTenancyStrategy org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryOptions.getMultiTenancyStrategy()'

The calling method's class, org.hibernate.search.cfg.impl.SearchConfigurationFromHibernateCore, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/Users/smaillns/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-search-orm/5.8.2.Final/hibernate-search-orm-5.8.2.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/search/cfg/impl/SearchConfigurationFromHibernateCore.class

The called method's class, org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryOptions, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/smaillns/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/orm/hibernate-core/6.2.6.Final/hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/boot/spi/SessionFactoryOptions.class
    jar:file:/Users/smaillns/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.11.Final/hibernate-core-5.2.11.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/boot/spi/SessionFactoryOptions.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryOptions: file:/Users/smaillns/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/orm/hibernate-core/6.2.6.Final/hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.hibernate.search.cfg.impl.SearchConfigurationFromHibernateCore and org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryOptions
```

Answer (score 3):

The Hibernate ORM version from [springboot-starter-jpa 3.1.2 is 6.2.6.Final](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/3.1.2#:%7E:text=Compile,Dependencies).
And your [hibernate search version 5.8](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/5.8/) is not compatible to Hibernate ORM 6.

By referring to [Compatibility of Hibernate Search 6.2](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.2/), you will need

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-mapper-orm-orm6</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

To be compatible to Hibernate ORM 6.

Since this is a major version change, you may want to refer to
[Hibernate search migration guide](https://hibernate.org/search/documentation/migrate/) for details.

Comment: now I got another error, since I've a multi-module application
`Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.arinashoe.userservice.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on BackendApplication: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'`

Comment: I think that the right solution for me is here 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/getting-started/orm/en-US/html_single/index.html#gettingstarted-dependencies